# Configuring roundcube with SSL for SMTP and IMAP

Tags: smtp, imap, roundcube

I have tried setting up SMTP and IMAP with a variety of settings and am unable to get anything working on my server. I have an SSL certificate on the server and can connect to it through https fine.

When I run round cubes auto configurator and test the configuration at the end, IMAP works and can log in but when I try and log into the account via "mydomain/roundcubemail", it does not work. (Pictures Below)

In configuration
[IMAP working in configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcocL.png)

**In mydomain/roundcubemail I get this error
With the error:**
IMAP log error: IMAP Error in /usr/share/roundcubemail/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php (184): Login failed for john@example.net from 193.61.254.32. AUTHENTICATE PLAIN: Authentication failed.

Furthermore, SMTP is failing to work with a NOT OKAY message.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcLVv.png)

And this is the configuration that I am using

```
$config['db_dsnw'] = 'mysql://roundcube:MYPASSWORD@localhost/roundcube';

$config['debug_level'] = 5;

$config['sql_debug'] = true;

$config['imap_debug'] = true;

$config['ldap_debug'] = true;

$config['smtp_debug'] = true;

$config['default_host'] = array('localhost:143', 'domain:143', 'ssl://domain:993');

$config['default_port'] = 993;

$config['smtp_server'] = 'ssl://domain';

$config['smtp_port'] = 465;

$config['smtp_user'] = '%u';

$config['smtp_pass'] = '%p';

$config['support_url'] = 'http://domain';

$config['des_key'] = 'myKey';

$config['username_domain'] = 'domain';

$config['product_name'] = 'Mail | domain';

$config['plugins'] = array();

$config['language'] = 'en_US';

$config['spellcheck_engine'] = 'pspell';

$config['draft_autosave'] = 60;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is either IMAP or SMTP working directly - i.e. without adding roundcube to the mix?

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old but can be useful for someone.

In order to get IMAP running with `SSL` or `TLS`, you must copy IMAP configuration from `config/defaults.inc.php` file to `config.inc.php`. And prefix your server address with `ssl://` or `tls://` depending upon your server configuration.
For example: `$config['default_host'] = 'ssl://imap.yourserver.tld';`

```php
//To use SSL/TLS connection, enter hostname with prefix ssl:// or tls://
$config['default_host'] = 'imap.yourserver.tld'; //your imap server address
$config['default_port'] = 143; //You must define the same port as your server
// IMAP AUTH type (DIGEST-MD5, CRAM-MD5, LOGIN, PLAIN or null to use
// best server supported one)
$config['imap_auth_type'] = 'LOGIN'; //You must define a authorization type
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to presume the configuration file you posted is the one you use. It seems strange that you have `domain` written in there so many times, but I will answer like the file is written like that.

That means that in most places you should substitute `domain` for what ever domain you are acutally using - in my examples it will be `example.dom`.

So to set up IMAP with secure sockets in roundcube, you need to change

```
$config['default_host'] = array('localhost:143', 'domain:143', 'ssl://domain:993');
```

to

```
$config['default_host'] = 'ssl://example.dom';
```

But in the case you are hosting your webmail on the same domain you are setting up mail for, consider using the `%n` (for the hostname) or `%t` (for the stripped hostname domain) replacement variables.

The same is true for SMTP:

```
$config['smtp_server'] = 'ssl://domain';
```

should change to

```
$config['smtp_server'] = 'ssl://example.dom';
```

or, if appropriate, to something containing `%n` or `%t`.

This all, of course, presumes there is a TLS IMAP server (such as [dovecot](https://www.dovecot.org/)) running on `example.dom:993`, and a TLS SMTP server (such as [OpenSMTPD](https://www.opensmtpd.org/)) on `example.dom:465`, and that those ports have been opened.